# Reflection rookie question about getting field value

Tags: vb.net

I have a class that contains the field value that I'm trying to get, but it is failing to a "Nothing" value.  Could you please give this rookie a hand?  Thanks in advance!

```
m445_Class_Type.GetField("ORR")
```

Comment: Not enough information, but typically `GetField(string)` methods are poor design choice. Leave it for dictionaries and database transfer types.

Comment: As this is a scenario where I am getting values from a string, loading them into a class for some additional updating, then inserting the data into SQL, do you have a suggestion as to how to better do this?  I only entered the OP as a question as to why, once the data is placed into the class why I then cannot get the value out of the class using reflection.  And yeah, I realize it is a rookie question but I will say that reflection confuses the heck out of me.

Comment: Ah, it's the reflection `GetField()`. It would be helpful if we had some more context than just the one line, but at least I can now say this does not get the value in the field, but rather an object that represents the field as a member of the type, and not associated with any instance of the type. Eventually you'll want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197004/3043

Comment: OK, I admit I am just not "getting it".  As I am not well versed in some of the terminology, I don't understand how reflection works and how it benefits my simple objective - to get a value from a class.  Can someone please clear this up for me?

Comment: Which instance of the class? We need to see a little more the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I have a class created with set and get for the field "ORR".  I have set the value into this class.  I have gotten the type of the class and am trying to get the value from the class using reflection.  That's pretty much all of the problem I'm experiencing.  And I do appreciate your comments, it's just that I'm not understanding.

Comment: When you define a class, you could then later create many instances of that class. Reflection needs to know which instance in order to get a value.

Comment: Hmm... I think I have enough to write an answer of some kind, but it'll need to go back to programming 101, where reflection is an advanced topic that should be avoided by beginners. That is: if you need my answer to explain what's going on, you probably should **NOT** be using reflection at all.

Comment: The reason that I am forced to use reflection is that in this same class are fields with names not of my choice:  JRR1, JRR2, etc.  Rather than having to write code for each specific field name, I'm trying to set up a loop to address "JRR" & a loop number.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a class like this:

```
class m445
{
    string ORR {get;set;} = "foo";
}
```

This **looks like** you have a class named `m445`, with a property (not a field!) named `ORR` having value `foo`.

*But that's not quite true!*

So far, we have only declared and defined the type: a sort of template for what future instances of the class might look like. To use this to ever actually get an `ORR` value, you must have an **instance** of the class. That is, you must do something like this:

```
var mym445Instance = new m445();
```

And now we can use reflection with the object instance associated with the `mym445Instance` variable to get the value of its `ORR` property:

```
var ORRValue = mym445Instance.GetType().GetProperty("ORR").GetValue(mym445Instance, null);
```

Or if we already have the `m445_Class_Type` object:

```
m445_Class_Type.GetProperty("ORR").GetValue(mym445Instance, null);
```

Of course, you might also have a completely different `m445` object instance:

```
var mym445Instance2 = new m445();
mym445Instance2.ORR = "bar";
```

And both of these instances might be active at the same time. Then you might do something like this:

```
m445_Class_Type.GetProperty("ORR").GetValue(mym445Instance2, null);
```

---

But the original code was calling `GetField()`, so maybe you have something more like this:

```
class m445
{
    private string ORR = "foo";

    public string GetOrr() {return ORR;}
    public void SetOrr(string input) {ORR = input;}
}
```

Now we have an actual field instead of a property. However, we *still need an instance of the class,* exactly like before:

```
var mym445Instance = new m445();
```

And now the reflection code will look like this:

```
var ORRValue = mym445Instance.GetType().GetField("ORR").GetValue(mym445Instance, null);
```

But note: **you should not build the class like this!** If this is how you wanted to write the class, just use a property instead.

---

It's also possible the distinction between properties and fields (and the need to use different reflection methods) is the main issue here.

---

I need to add that **you should not create a new instance just to check the field/property value**. All of this only has any meaning if there's already an instance variable somewhere you can use.

---

One more thing I noticed out of the comments:

> in this same class are fields with names not of my choice: JRR1, JRR2, etc. Rather than having to write code for each specific field name, I'm trying to set up a loop to address "JRR" & a loop number.

We **don't** need a specific instance yet to get the type or property references, such that you could do something like this **once** early in the program (perhaps has a static member of the class):

```
Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> m445properties = new();

m445properties.Add("ORR", m445_Class_Type.GetProperty("ORR"));
m445properties.Add("JRR1", m445_Class_Type.GetProperty("JRR1"));
m445properties.Add("JRR2", m445_Class_Type.GetProperty("JRR2"));
m445properties.Add("JRR3", m445_Class_Type.GetProperty("JRR3"));
```

And then put add a method like this to the class:

```
public object GetValue(this m445 src, string propertyName)
{
    return m445properties[propertyName].GetValue(src, null);
}
```

And now the code to get a value is **greatly simplified**, like this:

```
var ORRValue = mym445Instance.GetValue("ORR");
```

Comment: God bless you, sir!  I have the answers I needed and I'm now able to move forward on this.

Comment: @MichaelSanders I just added one additional piece at the end of the answer you should check.

Comment: Note for the case where you do `GetField` on `ORR`, the field is private, so you might need to specifically tell the reflection to consider private members.  I know non-default flags are needed for some reflection operations but I don't remember if that's needed for this one specifically.